# After migrating from MySQL 5.7.16 to MariaDB 10 database fails to start

Tags: mysql, mariadb, migration, mysqldump, mysql-5.7

MySQL Server Version is `5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

I want to switch over to MariaDB, but I can't get MariaDB to accept the existing database. I also tried doing a slow shutdown with InnoDB Engine and importing the database as `.sql` created with `mysqldump`.

The import of the `.sql` fails because the `mysql.user` table is different and I need to keep passwords, users and grants.

After migration I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged or in unsupported 3.20 format.

This is the final error before the DB fails to start.

Also `mysql_upgrade` does not work.

How should I perform the migration?

---

Edit:

[This](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11170?focusedCommentId=89442&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-89442) didn't work either ([Official Bug Report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11170)).

Comment: 10.what?  Perhaps 10.2 is more likely to work.

Comment: what if you dont import mysql database and just import user defined database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by dumping the MySQL database and reimporting it with MariaDB.